# Pointing AzureDevops to local repository manager (Nexus)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, artifacts, maven-central, on-premises-instances

How can I configure Azure Devops to point to repository manager instead of maven central repository for upstream resources ? 
**P.S. - I don't want to make changes in my projects pom.xml or settings.xml to use the repository manager directly.** Is there a way by which default maven central url for upstream resources can be changed in Azure Devops to locally installed repository manager like Apache Archiva or Nexus ?
Thnx.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @Hugh, I don't have any update from my side. The issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way by which default maven central url for upstream
>   resources can be changed in Azure Devops to locally installed
>   repository manager.

I am afraid this is currently unachievable in azure devops . When we add upstream sources in feed settings, we can only choose public sources or Azure Artifacts feeds as upstream sources.

[image]

For public sources, choose `npmjs`, `NuGet Gallery`, `PyPI`, or `Maven Central`.

**Note**:*You can also configure a custom upstream source for public repositories other than those listed above. Custom upstream sources are **only available for npm**.*

This is stated in this official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#add-public-upstream-sources-to-an-existing-feed).

Comment: I was just thinking that there must be some place in AzureDevops where this maven central URL has been configured and if I can find it, I can try to edit it...What do you say.. That might work ? The problem is "We don't want to open internet connection to maven central from the server where AzureDevops is installed and therefore trying to configure an already existing repository manager URL in AzureDevops".

Comment: Maven central URL is defined in azure devops source code, I am afraid you cannot modify it. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site.